# ASP.Net MVC3 model binding bug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've found a wierd scenario that prevents a bool? being posted back to the controller correctly. It's a very specific problem so follow the steps to recreate.

The application must be deployed as a virtual folder in IIS so that instead of /Home/Test the URL is /Virtual/Home/Test.

Home Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test(int? temp, bool? testBool)
{
    return View(testBool);
}
```

/Home/Test View (Razor cshtml):

```
@model bool?
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.CheckBox("testBool", Model ?? false, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
    @Html.Label(Model == true ? "True" : "False")
}
```

On post back the bool? doesn't make it to the controller because of the int? before it in the parameter list. This can be solved by putting the bool? before the int? in the parameter list but obviously you shouldn't have to do this. It also works fine if not in a Virtual folder on IIS. The same problem exists if using a POST method too although posting a bool rather than a bool? does work but isn't necessary if not on a virtual folder so shouldn't have to do this either.

Has anyone else experienced this and is there anything that explains why binding fails or is it just a bug in MVC3?

If it is just a bug, does anyone know what are the proper ASP.Net MVC channels for submitting bug reports?

**Update:**

I've found that if you have any number of nullable variables in the action parameters, only the first one will ever work and all others will fail to be populated. Anyone know if this is by design or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is still an issue. Thought it would have been fixed by now. One way around this particular bug is to add this to your `Application_Start` method.

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
```

Adding that will allow nullable parameters to behave appropriately. I'm surprised this bug still exists as it was known as of RC2 in December.

The difference between the route optional parameters in the article by haacked is that, in your example, routing isn't the problem. In this case you're posting (or querystring) data and that isn't populating your nullable action parameters properly. I've checked the mvc3 source and don't see why this should be a problem as debugging it it seems to work properly and stepping through the source results in the expected behavior. I'm fairly certain this hasn't been fixed even though Scott Guthrie said it should be by now...

Comment: That worked! Excellent. Just added the line you said to the Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs as instructed. Was starting to worry nobody would have the answer to this one. Hopefully the bug can be solved by the MVC team in a future update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome, @Chris. Glad it worked out for you. Strangely enough it works when in local debugging which makes me wonder what version I have installed on my test server... :)

Comment: Maybe you have a newer version of MVC3 than I do. I'll have to check if there is a newer version available. Did you definitely have it on a virtual directory like /Virtual/Home/Test? There are quite a few bits if not done right will cause it to work all of which I detailed in my post though.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I did because your requirements were rather strange to me :) I'm updating my version now to the most recent to see if this is still an issue.

Comment: I think I have version 3.0.20105.0 installed. Let me know if you have a newer version than this and where you got the latest from as I think last download I got, www.asp.net/mvc and www.microsoft.com/downloads had different installs and neither seems to specify what the exact version is.

Comment: @Chris, updating the server to the latest version with the tools update works without the `ModelMetaDataProvider` code. Looks like they did fix it...I gotta keep my server up to date.

Comment: @BuildStarted, what do you mean by tools update? I usually just get a download from Microsoft site.

Comment: The tools update has the following update:`Change: Changed the default ModelMetadataProvider back to DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` which explains why it works. The Tools Update is available in the Web Platform Installer as well as from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=82cbd599-d29a-43e3-b78b-0f863d22811a

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'm updating now and hopefully I won't need the patch anymore :)

Comment: If you have MVC 3 RTM installed you should not have to install anything. In the final release the default value of `ModelMetadataProviders.Current` is `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`. Also note that the Tools Update does not contain any changes to the runtime. I believe both of you simply had the RC2 or earlier version installed.

Comment: @marcind, the release notes for MVC3 Tools updated stated the above but yeah, on  my remote server you were correct. Local machine was fine though. :)

Comment: @marcind, I thought I had the RTM but the install was from mid-Jan 2011 I think so possibly was an older version. Either way, I'm installing the latest updates for both MVC3 Tools and VS2010 SP1 now and hopefully the problem will be resolved. Will confirm shortly.

Comment: @BuildStarted, @marcind: Even after the update of MVC3 Tools, I still need to manually set the ModelMetadataProviders.Current to make my scenario work which is odd because it starts off as a DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider but won't work unless I assign a new one.